# Can I create dimensional array from the string?

Tags: python, string, function, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am absolutely new programmer and I found a problem. I want to create a dimensional list from string. Is it possible? I tried different solutions but nothing works. Desire output is [[A,B,C],[B,C,A],[C,A,B]. My code:

```
def making_dimensional_list(string):
    a = []
    for i in range(len(string)):
        a.append([])
        for letter in string:
            a[i].append(letter)
    return a
print(making_dimensional_list("""ABC
BCA
CAB"""))
```

Comment: You just want to convert the string to a list of lists, right?

Comment: Yes, I want to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into its lines with the `splitlines` method, and convert each line to a list:

```
def multiline_to_list(s):
    return [list(line) for line in s.splitlines()]
```